# Add days to a date in PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to add number of days to a column. Below is the code I need to modify:

```
DATE_TRUNC('day', a.targetdeliverydateforcalc) + COALESCE(a.to_transit_time_amount, 0) + 2
```

I tried this (and similar variations):

```
DATE_TRUNC('day', a.targetdeliverydateforcalc) + INTERVAL ||COALESCE(a.to_transit_time_amount, 0) + 2 || 'day')
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Coming from an Oracle background I see that I have MUCH to learn in Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways come to mind to solve this. Computing the days then converting to an interval:

```
DATE_TRUNC('day', a.targetdeliverydateforcalc)::date + (COALESCE(a.to_transit_time_amount, 0) + 2)*interval '1 day'
```

or calculate the number of days and just add the resulting integer:

```
DATE_TRUNC('day', a.targetdeliverydateforcalc)::date + (COALESCE(a.to_transit_time_amount, 0) + 2)
```

Comment: `DATE_TRUNC('day', a.targetdeliverydateforcalc)::date` can be simplified to `a.targetdeliverydateforcalc::date`

Answer (score 0):

I would usually express this as:

```
(DATE_TRUNC('day', a.targetdeliverydateforcalc) + 
 (COALESCE(a.to_transit_time_amount, 0) + 2) * INTERVAL '1 DAY'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `make_interval()` function:

```
DATE_TRUNC('day', a.targetdeliverydateforcalc)
    + make_interval(days => COALESCE(a.to_transit_time_amount, 0) + 2)
```